# Fatal error: Call to undefined function menu_load_all()

Tags: routes

I have (D7) code that uses [menu_load_all()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!menu!menu.module/function/menu_load_all/7) to get a list of menus to pass as options for checkboxes to the admin interface of a module I'm writing.

To test and make sure my little snippet was returning the correct values for menu titles, I pasted it into a block of eval'd code in the content of my staging site, and it was fine. It returned a nice little array of titles and so I straight copy/pasted it into my module's code.

Now when I enable my module, I get this error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function menu_load_all()
```

WTH? Why did this work in eval'd and not in my module, and what do I do to get my module access to this API function?

[Full code of module available for your perusal](http://softpixel.com/~bbinkovitz/Foreshadowing-Menus).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing I can of is that you're calling `menu_load_all()` in `hook_install()` or `hook_enable()`; all system module files aren't necessarily included when those hooks are invoked.

If that's the problem, you can force the file with the function to be included by adding the following line of code to the top of your `hook_enable()`/`hook_install()` function:

```
module_load_include('module', 'menu');
```

Comment: This sounds like a helpful answer, but you'll forgive me for not being able to understand it. It seems from your answer that menu_load_all() is supposed to be called inside a hook_ function? Can I not just call functions that appear in core modules in my own module code? (After listing the dependency, of course)

Comment: You can't call anything directly in the module file, no, it would have to be inside a function of some sort (if the code is directly in the module file that would explain why you're getting the error, as the menu module file wouldn't necessarily be loaded when *your* module file is parsed by PHP). Are you trying to alter an existing form, or provide your own form?

Comment: I'm trying to add my own form, specifically, a config panel where the user selects which menus to create extra blocks for.

Comment: Ah ok...have you implemented hook_menu() and provided a page callback function for the form?

Comment: Yes, I tried to. I also tried adding module_load_include() but got "Fatal error: Call to undefined function menu_load_all()"

Comment: Would you be able to post your module code in the question?

Comment: There's a very, very small error in your code...underneath the comments for `Page callback: foreshadow menu settings` you have a few lines of code outside of the `foreshadow_menu_form()` function. Those 6 lines need to be *inside* that function...then everything should start working